# Hibernate primitive type mapping

Tags: hibernate, annotations

In Hibernate is it possible to join one of an entity column with another table using Java primitive type?

For example

```
@JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_ID",  referencedColumnName = "LABEL", insertable=false, updatable=false, table="ITEM_DATA")
private String itemLabel;
```

I just need the label of Item on load, is there any annotation I can use to workaround this problem?

Looking forward to your answers.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1) Create a view in the database that has that property and map the entity to that property (this can give you some problems with updates, depending on the DB you use)

2) Add an Item_Data property to the class (mapped to the ITEM_DATA table, with proper FK), and then wrap the getLabel property:

```
public virtual string getItemLabel{ get { return Item.label; } }
```

Anyway hibernate has to do the join to get correct property, so at least you have the whole object in case you have need to access more properties in the future

Comment: I did it the way you explained on the 2. option. Loading that object in memory is too expensive that' why I want to use String. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Did you use lazy loading? If you are not using the property all the time, in that way hibernate would only load the object when is going to use the property... or go for the view

Comment: I did use lazy. Well I guess the way I think is wrong. I have to use a pojo as u say. Thnks